# How would I borrow two element inside a loop?

Tags: rust

What's a good way to operate on one element in an array while still having access to the rest of the array? For example, below is some sample code that does not compile:

```rust
fn example(&mut self, n: usize) {
   for i in 0..n {
      if Some(x) = &mut self.items[i] {
         // some code modifying x

         // j = some other index dependent on x
   
         if self.items[j].is_some() { // <--------- cannot borrow self.items[j]
            // do something to x
         } else {
            // do something else to x
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here `j` cannot be determined until `x` is read, and element `j` in the array is being read only. Would this be a good candidate to use `unsafe` (I'm also using tokio so I'm not sure if that would cause unintended consequences)?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code is missing a `let` at the `if` statement, a `struct` definition and an `impl` (as the first parameter is `self` and should therefore be part of an `impl`). Further, some minimal code to determine `j` would be nice, to at least make it compile and reproduce the compilation error you are getting.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it using only safe code is with [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut):

```
fn example(&mut self, n: usize) {
    for i in 0..n {
        let (head, tail) = self.items.split_at_mut(i);
        let (cur, tail) = tail.split_at_mut(1);
        if Some(x) = &mut cur[0] {
            // some code modifying x

            // j = some other index dependent on x

            let other = if j < i {
                head[j]
            } else if j > i {
                tail[j - i - 1]
            } else {
                panic!("Need to special-case if j may be equal to i")
            };
            if other.is_some() {
                // do something to x
            } else {
                // do something else to x
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While `split_at_mut` would be a solution, I think in your case the easiest way with the least amount of special cases is to temporarily release `x` and re-borrow it after accessing `items[j]`:

```rust
struct X {
    items: Vec<Option<i32>>,
}

impl X {
    fn example(&mut self, n: usize) {
        for i in 0..n {
            if let Some(x) = &mut self.items[i] {
                *x += 1;

                let j = if *x < 5 { 0 } else { 1 };
                let j_is_some = self.items[j].is_some();

                // Reborrow - Unwrap is fine here because we already know
                //            that `items[i]` is `Some`.
                let x = self.items[i].as_mut().unwrap();
                if j_is_some {
                    *x += 10;
                } else {
                    *x -= 10;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = X { items: vec![Some(0), None, Some(3), Some(7), Some(10)] };
    println!("{:?}", x.items);
    x.example(4);
    println!("{:?}", x.items);
}
```

```
[Some(0), None, Some(3), Some(7), Some(10)]
[Some(11), None, Some(14), Some(-2), Some(10)]
```